# Youtube Data API v3 - problems with quota usage

Tags: youtube-api, quota, youtube-data-api

In my application I want to use quota that is user based (requests/second/user). I'am sending random (for test queries) **quotaUser** with all of my requests. But, in the console, I see an increase in the overall use of the quota ([project console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU65F.png)). The transfer of the **quotaUser** parameter does not affect anything. Perhaps I did not correctly understand the documentation on the use of quotas. Is it possible to execute more than 1,000,000 requests per day from multiple application users?

Here is my code:

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(SITE_PATH . '/vendor/access_data.json');
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/test', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    if (isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        $userId = rand(1000, 100000);
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $token = $client->getAccessToken();
        $client->setAccessToken($token);

        $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status,brandingSettings', array(
            'mine' => 'true',
            'quotaUser' => $userId
        ));

        $videoResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
            'playlistId' => $channelsResponse['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'],
            'maxResults'=> '50',
            'quotaUser' => $userId
        ));
        $videos = [];
        foreach($videoResponse['items'] as $video)
        {
            $videos[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
        }
        while(isset($videoResponse['nextPageToken']))
        {
            $videoResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
                'playlistId' => $channelsResponse['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'],
                'maxResults'=> '50',
                'pageToken' => $videoResponse['nextPageToken']
            ));
            foreach($videoResponse['items'] as $video)
            {
                $videos[] = $video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
            }
        }

        print_r($videos);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, have you fix the problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. And such a decision in this context does not exist. I solved the problem by creating a set of keys and monitoring the use of quotas for each of them.